# Prompt when `elementId` not found

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, runtime-error

I have VBA code that navigates through webpages by clicking on `elementId`.

When the `elementId` is found it provides desired result.

My problem is, there is no error prompted when the `elementId` is not found. The code continues till the end.

---

For example, the code:

```vb
Ie.visible = True
Ie.navigate "www.abc.com"

Ie.document.getElementbyId("btk").click
```

Here, I am trying to click on the button `btk`.

But this button is not available on the webpage.
I was expecting for my code to crash but it continues till the end.
No error handling being used in the code.

Comment: you'll need to loop through all the objects on the and test the id for `btk`. If it's found click it, if not do something else.

Comment: Can you please help me to refine the code if required, which I have written based on your suggestion

```
Dim htmla as mshtml.ihtmlelement
Dim htmlas  as mshtml.ihtmlelementcollection


For each htmla in htmlas
If htmla.getattribute(“id") = “btk" then
Htmla.click
Exit for
Else exit sub
Next htmla
```

Comment: Its better if you place that code in the actual question. It's very hard to read code in comments. However, it looks like you are exiting the sub if the id doesn't match "btk". That will surely fail on the first element if the id isn't "btk". Just remove the `Else exit sub` altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Scott Holtzman, @tdmsoares, @Deepak-MSFT for responding to my query.

Unfortunately upgrade of application and OS is not in my control so I have opted to use if statements.

Using the if statement, I have raised custom error when the button is not found to get run time error.

When I know the elementid that needs to be clicked, used the below method.

```
Dim buttonElement As HtmlElement
Set buttonElement = Ie.document.getElementById("btk")

If Not (buttonElement Is Nothing) Then
    buttonElement.click
Else:
   Err.raise vbObjectError+515,,”The sign in button was not found"
   
End If
```

When there is a need to search through elements to find out the button  to click, used below method

````
Dim htmla as mshtml.ihtmlelement
Dim htmlas as mshtml.ihtmlelementcollection

Signin= 0
For each htmla in htmlas
If htmla.getattribute(“classname”) = “hero_button" Anand htmla.innertext =”Sign in" then
signin= signin+1
Htmla.click
Exit for
Next htmla
If signin<>1 then
Err.raise vbObjectError +515,,” The sign in button was not found"
End if
```
````

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: How do I mark this Solved or Answered. I don't see options to mark it

Comment: There will be right tick icon beside your answer. Click on it to mark it as an answer. See here: https://imgur.com/a/7fRzBRd

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, you would like to check if `elementId` representing the button `btk` in the webpage really exists before you call the click event.

One way of doing this is creating an object (I will call it buttonElement) and try to set it to the button with id `btk` (using `getElementById("btk")`, if it doesn't exist in the webpage, the object `buttonElement` will be `Nothing`, but if it exists, the object will get a reference to this button

```vb
Dim buttonElement As HtmlElement
Set buttonElement = Ie.document.getElementById("btk")
'
If Not (buttonElement Is Nothing) Then
    buttonElement.click
Else:
   '
   'Do something else, buttonElement with id btk not found
End If
```

Comment: I was expecting vba to return error on it's own without the if statement.

Comment: Say for example when we are working with spreadsheets. If we refer to a spreadsheet that is not present in a workbook, vba returns some error. I was expecting the same to happen when my code interacts with webpages

Comment: @Anand Remembers that using vba to control IE is like a workaround, if the element you click is `nothing` and the vba doesn't prompt an error it's not your fault. But it's always good practice see if the element is or not `nothing` (In VBA the object default value is `nothing` and not `null`). Using the `if` statement you can trigger a `MsgBox` or raise a custom error

Comment: Also, maybe the error is not triggered because you're using the click method for the element. In cases as trying to set a text to an input element you can get `Automation Error`. So It's always recommended to check if the reference to the element is 'nothing' or not before calling other procedures

Comment: `I was expecting vba to return error on it's own without the if statement` - that is not how it works in this case. Working with external library objects does not always work the same as working with Excel's Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to update your Windows OS and MS Office with the latest updates that may help you to fix this issue.

I have tested the issue with the simple code on Windows 10 OS with MS Office 2016.

I can see that it is generating an error if the code does not find the element on the page.

Tested code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     
    IE.Visible = True
    
    URL = "http://localhost/86.html"
   
    IE.Navigate URL
  
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    IE.document.getElementById("abc").Click
    
    Set IE = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]